# Setting Maven for Artifactory deploy

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I've followed the tutorial from [Setting up Artifactory 4 as a Maven repository](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLIX-dwEKGw) but I have a problem running `mvn deploy` command. In the video things looked pretty straight forward but for me I get a `Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.` error.
This was working in Artifactory 3 but generating settings.xml file and also password generating seems to be changed. 
There is something I am missing in the configuration? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your `settings.xml` for the correct `<server>` tags. Once you added `<distributionManagement>` tag in your `pom.xml`, you should add the corresponding `<server>` tag with the same ID and URL to the `settings.xml`.

Comment: this was the problem I had, but it worked only by modifying the url, the id part is different and the upload works. But I still face a issue because every artifact seems to be uploaded anonymously. I still cannot found a way to set the username and password in settings.xml

Comment: Yeah, maven totally ignoring the id, matching the servers by URL, go figure why.

Comment: I can't understand this. Maybe that is the reason I get only anonymously uploads. I will try putting the same ID